# Object or an array defined in model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Not able to identify the difference between declaration of object or array in a Mongoose schema

Schema :

```
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var user = new Schema({
        _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Admin'},
        name: {type: String, ref: 'Admin'}
    });
```

`User : [user] or user` In this which one is object and which one is an array

Comment: [read the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/model-definition.html)

Comment: An array requires square brackets `[]` which you don't have. So there are no arrays involved in your example...

Comment: You create a user object with a name and id. There should be a users collection that is an array and hold the user objects you create using the schema above.

Comment: Yeah it was like Creator : [user]  which is an array not object so changed it to Creator : user now